# load matching files in table

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl

I have a folder that contains multiple .csv files for each employee like empname_date.csv and I want to load files in one table.
Not all files but only files where file name matches the data with tbl_empmaster table that contains the master list of employees.

I do not want to check each file because it will take too much of time. I need to filter files as per master list and then load the matching employee files.

Please help what I can do in this case.

**I am using SSIS to do the same.**

Answer (score 1):

Create an SSIS Package to with a *For Each Loop Container* to Read all the CSV files of the given Folder.

Read the File Name without extension to a variable and Before inserting perform a table lookup to see whether the given File Name exists in your table and insert only if the match is found

Comment: In this case, i have to check each file. I am trying to optimize the process and want to filter files that contain only matching names.

Comment: please comment.

Comment: Then try reading all file names to an Array or Object then from that object match the file names and flag those need to be processed and read only the flagged files in the Data Flow